# (sass) How to type this mixin right?

Tags: html, css, sass, web-deployment

sorry if this question is dump
I'm trying to learn sass and I'm practicing by rebuilding a website but I've problem with media mixins I don't know if it's typo or I'm doing it wrong hope someone help

```
@mixin respond($breakpoint)
  @if $breakpoint == phone
    @media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) @content

  @if $breakpoint == tab-port
    @media only screen and (max-width: 56.25em) @content

  @if $breakpoint == tab-land
    @media only screen and ( max-width: 75em ) @content

  @if $breakpoint == big-desktop
    @media only screen and ( max-width: 112.5em ) @content
```

that's screenshots for the code and the error

[the sass code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LildJ.png)

[the cmd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yxrB.png)

Comment: The problem is that you need to put `@content` on the next line for each of your `if` statements.

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. [Don't post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.